# Can you pass commands to a VM from the host server?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have written a batch file to set the IP address of a host server and the two virtual machines running on it. At the moment you have to copy the script onto each machine and run it which isn't what I want, I would like to run the script on the host server and have the commands passed to each VM.

Is this possible?

Comment: You might have better luck asking this on [SU].

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I've just posted on there too.

Comment: Please don't double post. If you think SuperUser is a better fit then remove this question. You can always reask if need be.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a powershell script which uses PsExec(comes with sysinternals) to run a scriptblock or script file on your vm machine.

It will look something like this:
PSExec \RPC001 -i -u myID -p myPWD PowerShell C:\script\StartPS.ps1

Apparantly targetting a VM could be more tricky, see this link for more information:
[Is there a way to psexec into my own virtual machine (windows xp mode)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28392688/is-there-a-way-to-psexec-into-my-own-virtual-machine-windows-xp-mode)